# Sources of PyS60's standard functions (particularly appuifw.query)

Tags: python, mobile, pys60

I need to give user ability to enter a time in form hh:mm:ss (with appropriate validation of course). And standard function `appuifw.query(u'Label', 'time')` works almost fine except that it allows to enter only hours and minutes (hh:mm). So I want to look though its source and write my own that enhances it in the stated manner.

I've found file `epoc32\winscw\c\resource\appuifw.py` that comes with PyS60 SDK extension but it only contains constructor implementation (`__init__`).

So the question is where to find sources of platform's standard functions (particularly `appuifw.query`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the [*_src.zip files](https://garage.maemo.org/frs/?group_id=854) on garage.maemo.org any useful? (I don't currently have the tools to verify what's in there.)